# Авторизация на сайте при помощи post запросов в redmine

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, redmine, webbrowser

Добрый пятница.

Прочитал десяток сайтов про авторизацию на сайте программно при помощи post запросов. Что-то не получается это сделать в redmine.

В адресную строку подставляю параметры - и ничего, выбрасывает на страницу авторизации все равно. Поглядел на страницу - используется только username, password и еще два скрытых поля, куда вернуться и какой-то гуид.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать свою оболочку для управления и формирования автоматических отчетов по выборкам. Парсить страничку не сложно, на сколько вижу, споткнулся, что не могу авторизоваться программно. Возможно потребуется как-то куукисы хранить, но это уже второй вопрос, после авторизации будет видно.

Работать напрямую с базой данных, не хочется, да и не правильно, в мое случае. Кучку аддонов посмотрел, ничего внятного для своих требований не нашел. Разбираться в "руби" и шаблонах редмайна нет желания.

Хотелось бы все на скриптах сделать и забыть.

ЗЫЖ В голову приходит самое пошлое решение, сделать все ночью на auto-it, но вы сами понимаете...

Спасибо.

---

**update:**

В адресную строку пытался вводить команду в следующем виде (с учетом комментария. Логин и пароль в данном случае неверные, а гуид меняется постоянно, т.е. тоже не верный).

http://demo.redmine.org/login?authenticity_token=+EHR8v0bI23QV6koa/RK244+X4OJ6XmXJSVIHh+jcqk=&back_url=http://demo.redmine.org&username=usr&password=pwd

Comment: ну, вы бы хоть пример какой оставили..

`http://demo.redmine.org/login` - это оно? 

`authenticity_token` выпарсиваете/передаёте?

Comment: @dthpth, дело в том, что Redmine находится в нашей фирме в закрытой сети, но да, демо подойдет, только логин и пароль соответственно мой сюда не подойдет :-)
передавал обратно 4 поля
authenticity_token
back_url
username
password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работу через [Rest API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api) Вы не рассматривали?

Comment: Спасибо, вроде подходит. Но теперь жутко интересно разобраться с этими post запросами. Где я лажаю?